# Create master detail form in infopath 2013 from sharepoint list

Tags: infopath

Here is very simple scenario , however I wonder why there is no guide about it anywhere .

I have two lists in SharePoint 
`Continent` and `Country`

In InfoPath 2013 I click blank form , I create two data connection, one for continent and one for country .

Now I want to show single entity from continent list and then in repeating table to show list of countries for that continent .

However I can't find any solution for that . In InfoPath 2010 i could manage master detail for repeating table , but I can't see that in InfoPath 2013 .

any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Infopath list forms don't support the Master/Detail for repeating tables. That only works in browser or filler forms, not in list forms. For list forms you need to create a rule that fires when the continent is selected.

In list forms you can either feed the selected continent to the country query and refresh the query, or you can filter the drop-down of the country based on the selected continent.

Comment: there will be no click , because the master record is selected by query string  parameter in sharepoint . so by default it is selected and user cant change it .

Comment: In that case use the filter method for the dependent dropdown. You can do that in the control properties.